# Pandas putting numbers/characters in reverse order when replacing '/'

Tags: pandas

`7/20/4582` is being replaced by `4582720` when using `str.replace` to replace '/' in pandas.

Any ideas on how to get the correct order?

Comment: What is the dtype of columns? Are you sure it's a string?

Comment: the dtype is dtype('O')

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Please post what you _actually_ used along with some sample code to reproduce. `pd.Series(['7/20/4582']).str.replace('/', '')` yields `7204582` just as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the problem. It appears when I was viewing the output  it was being intercepted as a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, given the following input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'float': [1.0],
                    'int': [1],
                    'datetime': [pd.Timestamp('20180310')],
                    'string': ["7/20/4582"]})
```

This code is for you:

```
df['string'] = df['string'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('/',''))
```

and gives:

```
   float  int   datetime   string
0    1.0    1 2018-03-10  7204582
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your column is a datetime column, so you might be more lucky with:

```
column.dt.strftime("%m%d%Y")
```

(column being your column you want to change) 
See [pandas.Series.dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) docs.

Comment: But if you load your data with read_csv for example, pandas might infer that the type is a datetime.

Comment: Well the column is mixed with different formats. So some model numbers have nothing, some have '-'  and some have '/'

Comment: Can you check the dtype of your column?

Comment: the dtype is dtype('O')